# My iphone 3gs won't connect to iTunes

Tags: iphone, itunes, windows

I've tried everything.

- reinstalling iTunes
- restarting Apple Mobile Device
- bought a different cable
- restarting my laptop
- restarting the iphone
- checked for iTunes Helper Services
- uninstalled and reinstalled Apple Mobile Device USBdriver

and **still**, my iPhone wont come up in iTunes but it does come up as my iPhone in My Computer as a portable device.

All I get in iTunes is `iTunes could not connect to this iPhone. An unknown error occured (0xE8000084)`

I've tried Googling for this error and no one else seems to have it.

Comment: Have you reset the iPhone to a factory-fresh state?

Answer (score 1):

This issue is because the iPhone 3GS isn't compatible with the newer iTunes software. I've been trying for ages and the only option I have come across so far is to take the phone to an Apple Store. I have tried everything. I have tried calling apple, chatting with them online and I have even tried to download an old version of iTunes but nothing works. Maybe give apple a call and see if they can give you any advice. Probably will tell you to take the phone into the store

Comment: Can you give a source outside of your own experience?